# How to run test suite collection with verbosity of tests in test suite -selenium+python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, testing, selenium-chromedriver

I am pretty much new to selenium and i am using python as language to write my tests.

I have created a class with all my tests[imagine this is my suite] and then call the class in my main file.[i have the collection here]

I wanted to know how i can display the verbosity of the tests being run even if i am running them as a collection from the suite.

Please let me know if you need more info.
For now it is just telling me that my tests is ok or failed.
[This is how the output is being generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iOaf.png)

Thank you